# Accepted answer not ranked first

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/power-up-initialization-of-hd44780-lcd-module) the accepted answer isn't always ranked first; sometimes it's preceded by another answer with same number of upvotes. It doesn't always happen, just like for other answers with the same number of upvotes their order changes randomly.
I haven't seen this behavior before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the answer is from the question owner.

Self-accepts do not dock to the top of the question, but rather follow the normal answer logic. Since this has 2 upvotes currently, that means it'll sort randomly among the other answers with 2 upvotes on the question.